# DOM get element methods

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="box">
    First collection
</div>

<div class="box">
    Second collection
</div>
```

Hi, I'm still studying the JS, I have this exercise that requires me to select the second 'box' class and store it into a variable, I just don't know how to do it, can someone help me, thank you.

I have tried using `document.GetElementsByClassName` and `document.querySelector` but I just don't know how to pick the second one and store it to a variable.

Comment: `let secondDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[1];` ?  What did you try and how specifically did it fail?

Comment: Should be a lowercase g in `GetElementsByClassName`. Read up on it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Thank you, I don't know that I can use index at the last of the document.getElementsByClassName like that.

Comment: There are a number of ways you could do it: `const div2 = document.querySelectorAll(".box")[1]`, `document.querySelector("div:nth-child(2)")`, loop through all the `div` elements and check the `textContent` to see if it is: `Second collection`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Both can be used:

`.getElementsByClassName('box')[1]`

```js
var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[1];
console.log(selected);
```

```html
<div class="box">
    First collection
</div>

<div class="box">
    Second collection
</div>
```

`.querySelector('.box:nth-of-type(2)')`

```js
var selected = document.querySelector('.box:nth-of-type(2)');
console.log(selected);
```

```html
<div class="box">
    First collection
</div>

<div class="box">
    Second collection
</div>
```

Comment: or `var selected = document.querySelectorAll('.box')[1]`;

Comment: or `.querySelector('div:nth-child(2)')`

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by using `.getElementByClassName` then it should return a list of item with the class name box in Array, then you can just simply select which boxes you want.

```
const boxes =  document.getElementsByClassName("box")

boxes[0]
boxes[1]
boxes[boxes.length]
```

Comment: boxes[boxes.length] is outside the range

Comment: `boxes[boxes.length-1] // only works when last item is desired`